# How do I build this simpler gadget?

Tags: digital-logic, counter

Up front I have almost no experience with this kind of thing. I'm a computer scientist so I understand logic gates and the like but I know near nothing about electricity.

What I want to do is build a device that has 2 buttons and a series of LEDs. When one of the buttons is pushed the leftmost unlit LED should light up and stay lit. When the other is pushed the leftmost lit LED should unlight. So it can be used to manually keep track of a count of something. I'm estimating that I'd have around 10 round LEDs.

I want it to be battery powered, as opposed to wall-powered. I was thinking about using a disposable 9 volt battery as a source. With typical LEDs that use 20 mA a piece, I found that the minimum current that this device would draw is 200 mA.

I've found a few beginner's guide type things that have counters but they're usually not button controlled or don't use lights and I've never seen one that has a button to go backwards.

Originally I thought this would be fairly easy but the more I research the more I'm getting completely lost.

Comment: You want a unary counter?

Comment: Uhm, yeah that would be accurate. I want it to be able to count down as well though.

Comment: Count down, or reset?

Comment: count down. I want one button that turns one more light on and and another that turns one light off. So I can keep track of a number of something going up and down.

Comment: Why can't you use: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003WJ45EI ? It's cheap. It's an up/down counter. And it can count a lot higher than a few lit LEDs can. Do you NEED LEDs? If so, why?

Comment: Aesthetic reasons. I want it to look like stored energy on a home made device. Plus this seemed like fun.

Comment: What size? Why LEDs and not some other display? How many LEDs? What's the power supply to be (battery?) Pocket portable? Why no micro usage? Is this for a learning experience only? If battery, how long do you expect it to last before replacing the battery? Talk a lot more about things in your question.

Comment: @jonk the LEDs are for aesthetic reasons. Probably about 10. And I'd like it to be easily portable. I could use micro but I don't know how or if I should. I'm really new to this. I'm doing this as sort of an arts and crafts thing, it's a combined learning experience and semi-useful prop for a game.

Comment: Battery? Or wall supply?

Comment: @jonk battery supply

Comment: There are _bar_ type LEDs and 3mm and 5mm round types. Do you have a preference? And are you thinking of using an 9V battery? Or some combo of AA batteries or AAA? How long do you want this to work before you need to replace the batteries? What kind of usage will it be put to? (Continuous days at a stretch?) How bright do the LEDs need to be? (There are some very bright ones and some rather lackluster ones.) Here is a bar type: http://media.digikey.com/photos/Kingbright%20Photos/MFG_WP1043GD_sml.jpg

Comment: @jonk oh ok. Uhm, round LEDs. I assumed it would be a 9v but I'm not really sure what kind of power supply something like this would need. I'll only be using it for a few hours a week. The LEDs should be visible in a well lit room but not hurt to look at.

Comment: Typical LEDs use 20mA. All 10 lit up would be 200mA total. A 9V battery might be okay with this, but it would only last a couple of hours. Plus, the voltage doesn't hold at 9V. It would drop a lot during the time it operates, so a circuit design would need to cope with that, as well. There are LEDs that only require 2mA or so. I think you might want to shoot for those.

Comment: I can't supply this as a design answer as it's not "design." But look at this from sparkfun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11365 With that unit, you have 9 LEDs, it uses a 9V battery, has a built in ATTiny micro from Atmel, and you can recode it. You'll need to get a software toolchain and you will need to get a way to connect to the programming header (USB to header programmer module for the Atmel ATTiny parts -- also cheap.) But that will get you something very close.

Answer (score 2):

You can build this kind of circuit relatively easily using a bidirectional shift-register like [CD54HC299](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hc299.pdf). If you pull DS0 high and DS7 low you can shift high values from left and low vales from right.

Use the buttons to pull either S0 or S1 high to set the shift direction.
You can drive the clock-input from both buttons but you may need to delay the clock by a few ms using a RC network.

The chip can drive up to 50mA (for all LEDs) which should be plenty for 8 LED indicators, if you don't mind them being relatively dark.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one LED to be lit (when the LED moves to the right, the previously lit one is extinguished) that is an up/down counter connected to a decoder. You can find logic chips to make this fairly easily, and power consumption is minimal because only one LED needs to be powered. Or use a micro as below.

If you want all the LEDs to be lit when the far right one is lit, that's called a "thermometer code" and it's not a particularly popular decoding scheme. It's probably most easily done with a micro (either a chip or something like an Arduino), although it could be done with a bunch of logic chips (for example, add a 2-input OR gate on each decoder output but the lowest that is wired to the next lowest OR gate output).

When you go to practically design something like this with logic chips, some of the decoders may be active low rather than active high so you may have to substitute different kinds of gates and/or add inverters to get the logic to work out right. For example, a NAND gate is like an OR gate with both inputs inverted, so an active-low decoder might need an inverter plus a NAND gate on each output.